# Bypass Location with Alias in Apache2

Tags: apache2

I'd like to know how to use Apache as a reverse proxy for a specific path and as local server for its sub-paths.

For a specific location, I am using Apache as a reverse proxy (`https://my.server.com/my-tools`):

```html
<Location /my-tools>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://10.1.1.11:3101/my-tools
    ProxyPassReverse http://10.1.1.11:3101/my-tools
</Location>
```

The thing is that for its assests I'd like to use the local server (`https://my.server.com/my-tools/images/`). I have tried adding Alias with no success:

```html
Alias /my-tools/images/ /home/myself/public/images/
<Directory /home/myself/public/images/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I tried also to add this, but it didn't work either:

```html
<Location /my-tools/images/>
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```

It keeps redirecting to the remote server when I enter `https://my.server.com/my-tools/images/myimage.png`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a direct example in the [mod_proxy `ProxyPass` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass):

> The `!` directive is useful in situations where you don't want to
>   reverse-proxy a subdirectory, e.g.
>
> ```
> <Location "/mirror/foo/">
>     ProxyPass "http://backend.example.com/"
> </Location>
> <Location "/mirror/foo/i">
>     ProxyPass "!"
> </Location>
> ```

In your situation that would be:

```
<Location "/my-tools/images">
    ProxyPass "!"
    Alias "/home/myself/public/images"
</Location>
<Location "/my-tools/">
    ProxyPass http://10.1.1.11:3101/my-tools/
    ProxyPassReverse http://10.1.1.11:3101/my-tools/
</Location>
```

Or with alternative syntax:

```
ProxyPass "/my-tools/images" "!"
Alias "/my-tools/images" "/home/myself/public/images"
ProxyPass "/my-tools/" "http://10.1.1.11:3101/my-tools/"
ProxyPassReverse "/my-tools/" "http://10.1.1.11:3101/my-tools/"
```

Comment: Thanks for point out the ProxyPass "!", but it didn't work as expected inside <Location> (at least in Apache 2.4). I had to move the `ProxyPass` out of the Location directive to make it work. Note: you need to put `ProxyPass !` before the `ProxyPass http://..."`. Also, `Alias` can't be placed inside Location.

Comment: Both have examples inside `<Location>` in the official documentation, but there's a limitation: "If the `Alias` directive is used within a `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` section the URL-path is omitted, and the file-path is interpreted using expression syntax.
This syntax is available in Apache 2.4.19 and later."

Comment: I improved my answer by adding both alternatives & full configuration.

Comment: Despite what documentation states, this error is shown when I put alias (without the URL, just like in @Esa example) inside Location: `Alias not allowed here`.